# Why do I get "/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7 is not a symbolic link"?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, cuda

After installing `CUDA` toolkit and `cuDNN` successfully without any issues, whenever I do :

```
sudo ldconfig
```

I get the :

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7 is not a symbolic link
```

error message.
what is the reason and how can I resolve this?

By the way, I have installed `cuDNN` like this :

```
 # cuDNN, extracts to a folder named cuda
 tar xvf cudnn*.tgz  
 cd cuda  
 sudo cp lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
 sudo cp include/* /usr/local/cuda/include
```

The output of `ls -lha libcudnn*` in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` is as follows:

```
breeze@breeze:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ ls -lha libcudnn*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 275M آوریل 15 12:03 libcudnn.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 275M آوریل 15 12:03 libcudnn.so.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 275M آوریل 15 12:03 libcudnn.so.7.0.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268M آوریل 15 12:03 libcudnn_static.a
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to dear God I found the solution using this [link](http://queirozf.com/entries/installing-cuda-tk-and-tensorflow-on-a-clean-ubuntu-16-04-install#-sbin-ldconfig-real-usr-local-cuda-lib64-libcudnn-so-5-is-not-a-symbolic-link).

> This may happen when you run sudo ldconfig after copying cuDNN files.
>
> After installing `cuDNN`, copying the extracted files to
>   `/usr/lib/cuda/lib64` and creating the symlinks, things may go wrong
>   with the symlinks.
>
> So go to `/usr/local/cuda/lib64/` and run `ls -lha libcudnn*`.
>
> You should see two symlinks (bold teal) and one single file. Something
>   like this:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/cuda/lib64$ ls -lha libcudnn*
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Dez 25 23:56 libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.5
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Dez 25 23:55 libcudnn.so.5 -> libcudnn.so.5.1.5
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 76M Dez 25 23:27 libcudnn.so.5.1.5
> ```
>
> The exact version of libcudnn.so.5.1.5 maybe be a little different for
>   you (maybe libcudnn.so.5.1.10). In that case, adapt the code
>   accordingly
>
> If `libcudnn.so` and `libcudnn.so.5` are not symlinks then this is the
>   reason why you got this error. If so, this is what you need to do:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo rm libcudnn.so
> /usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo rm libcudnn.so.5
> /usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo ln libcudnn.so.5.1.5 libcudnn.so.5
> /usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo ln libcudnn.so.5 libcudnn.so
> Run sudo ldconfig again and there should be no errors
> ```

After running the 
`ls -lha libcudnn*` in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` and seeing :

```
breeze@breeze:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ ls -lha libcudnn*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 275M آوریل 15 12:03 libcudnn.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 275M آوریل 15 12:03 libcudnn.so.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 275M آوریل 15 12:03 libcudnn.so.7.0.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268M آوریل 15 12:03 libcudnn_static.a
```

I had to do :

```
breeze@breeze:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo rm libcudnn.so
[sudo] password for breeze: 
breeze@breeze:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo rm libcudnn.so.7
breeze@breeze:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo ln libcudnn.so.7.0.5 libcudnn.so.7
breeze@breeze:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo ln libcudnn.so.7 libcudnn.so
breeze@breeze:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ sudo ldconfig
```

And everything is back to normal:)

Comment: Technically a symbolic link, as referred to by the error message, is created with 'ln -s' instead of simply 'ln', as suggested in the answer, which would create a hard link.

Answer (score 8):

Check

```
wxf:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ ls -al libcudnn.so*
...
...
-rwxr-xr-x  3 root root 302770160 Jan 27 14:30 libcudnn.so          NO link
-rwxr-xr-x  3 root root 302770160 Jan 27 14:30 libcudnn.so.7        NO link
-rwxr-xr-x  3 root root 302770160 Jan 27 14:30 libcudnn.so.7.3.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 349141232 Jan 27 14:30 libcudnn.so.7.4.2
...
...
```

No link `->`

(check all links: `sudo ldconfig -v`)

Because

(cudnn downloaded from nvidia has symbolic link)

```
wxf:~/cudnn/cuda/lib64$ ls -al
total 974632
drwxrwxr-x 2 wxf wxf      4096 Jan 19 19:50 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 wxf wxf      4096 Jan 19 19:50 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wxf wxf        13 Dec 12 01:58 libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 wxf wxf        17 Dec 12 01:58 libcudnn.so.7 -> libcudnn.so.7.4.2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 wxf wxf 302770160 Sep 21 01:36 libcudnn.so.7.3.1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 wxf wxf 349141232 Dec 12 01:30 libcudnn.so.7.4.2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wxf wxf 346085818 Dec 12 01:30 libcudnn_static.a
```

When we copy, we lost symbolic info.

Go to `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`

```
sudo ln -sf libcudnn.so.7.4.2 libcudnn.so.7

sudo ln -sf libcudnn.so.7 libcudnn.so
```

Now,

```
wxf:/usr/local/cuda/lib64$ ls -al libcudnn.so*
...
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        13 Jan 27 14:43 libcudnn.so -> libcudnn.so.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        17 Jan 27 14:43 libcudnn.so.7 -> libcudnn.so.7.4.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 302770160 Jan 27 14:30 libcudnn.so.7.3.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 349141232 Jan 27 14:30 libcudnn.so.7.4.2
...
```

Comment: An explanation on whats going on here and why would be much appreciated